# SQL Select of SharePoint Dates off ? MOSS 2007

Tags: custom-list, date-time, sql

Does anybody know what this is about?  They seem to be off by a bunch of hours and they look right in SharePoint but not SQL

[image]

I also see the problem in my Data view Webpart, but it's clearly coming in like that from SQL.

But here is my client formating where I just took off the time, but I want it back but only correct.

Answer (score 0):

this is about the regional settings present in sharepoint for more info see [this documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/specify-regional-settings-HA010177473.aspx).

basically, if you want in your SQL and in SharePoint and in your local to be of the same. you should get the server regional settings and your personal regional settings to be the same. since the SQl really is just using what the server regional setting is defined and the sharepoint would just align that specific regional settings based on your personal regional settings to display in SharePoint the corresponding date and time for you.

Regional settings is basically the time zone use by yourself or your system. personal regional settings is the timezone set in your locals and the server is the time zone of the actual server

Comment: Can you please extend this answer with some guidelines of how to fix the issue, to make it more independent from the link

Comment: Regional settgings on the site seem fine. How do you adjust it for the SQL server or in SQL 2005?

Comment: Do you mean that your local regional settings and site regional settings is already matched? if so it is expected that the data that would be inputter in your sql server would matched your local dates and time

Comment: Yes.they match. to confirm, Where exactly do you get local regional settings in SQL 2005 Windows 2003?